# Logical approach to “nobody’s”

Tags: negation, logic

“I didn’t grow up under anybody’s care”.
It means “I grew up under no care”.

To express it, isn’t “I grew up under nobody’s care” incorrect?

Logically, I think it should be “I grew up under no body’s care”, because “nobody’s care” means “care which belongs to nobody” so it means “I grew up under care” but “no body’s care” means “no care which belongs to somebody” so it means “I grew up under no care”.

Comment: Where is it written that English must be logical?

Comment: @Michael Woke Harvey No, it doesn’t need to be, but I just wonder if it’s against logic. I don’t care much actually.

Comment: I see little if any "logic" in your assertion that "nobody's care" refers to *care which does in fact exist, but isn't associated with anyone*. But even if there *were* any logic to that proposition, it wouldn't imply that splitting "nobody" back into two separate words would make any difference. This question pointlessly depends on perverse interpretation of a syntactic construction that most native speakers would never even recognise as being open to [deliberate?] misinterpretation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As you said, “care which belongs to nobody” is simply care that does not exist. In short, “no care.” Conversely, “no body’s care” actually means that it wasn’t a person’s care, but could be an animal, or a group, etc. and has wider interpretation than the first phrase. OP has it backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Words like "nobody" or "nothing" create negative sentences, even when the verb is positive.

So "There is nothing in the box" has the same meaning as "There is not anything in the box."

That is logical enough, in the sense that that is following the rules of English.

Likewise, you can form a negative sentence either with a negative verb phrase "I didn't grow up under anybody's care".  Or you can use one of these special words that can give a negative sense "I grew up under nobody's care"

The latter is probably preferred, as it doesn't have the potential interpretation of "I didn't grow up under anybody's care" = "I stayed small while people cared for me".  In this case, this interpretation is nonsensical, in other similar examples, ambiguity could be created.

The potential for negatives to be in the verb or from words like nobody allows for the formation of sentences like "I didn't grow up under nobody's care".  And these double negatives do create problems of interpretation, as different sociolects interpret the meaning differently.

Answer (score 0):

Um, it seems like you’re trying to break down AAVE, and I must say, the ELL forum is not the place to do that. Also, trying to approach regional dialect with logic is simply… incorrect. Languages don’t work that way. You can’t explain regional dialects’ digression from their “root language” through *logic.*

Comment: Thank you. “Care that doesn’t exist” makes me understand perfectly.